# Can I modify a struct property and send it back to the contract?

Tags: web3js, struct

we are experiencing an issue dealing with structs.
We expect to modify a struct property after getting it from an event in web3js, but, it seems that the modify does not apply.

Any ideas?

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.3;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Example {
  struct Structure {
    uint value;
  }

  event Created(
    Structure structure
  );

  event Modified(
    Structure structure
  );

  constructor() public {}

  function create() public {
    emit Created(Structure(42));
  }

  function modify(Structure memory structure) public {
    emit Modified(structure);
  }
}
```

web3js code:

```
  let Example = artifacts.require('Example')
  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

  Example.deployed()
    .then(instance => {
      instance.Created(async (err, evt) => {
        let structure = evt.returnValues.structure
        console.log('Created: ' + structure.value)
        structure.value = 21
        console.log('Modify: ' + structure.value)
        await instance.modify(structure, { from: accounts[0] })
      })

      instance.Modified((err, evt) => {
        let structure = evt.returnValues.structure
        console.log('Modified: ' + structure.value)
        callback()
      })

      instance.create({ from: accounts[0] })
    })
```

log:

```
Created: 42
Modify: 21
Modified: 42
```

We expected the modified value equals to 21

Comment: console.log the structure, but my guess is that you have to modify something like structure[0]. Taking a JavaScript object from an event and passing it as a function parameter is probably not a great idea, though.

Comment: the structure console.log are:
```
[ '42', value: '42' ]
[ '42', value: 21 ]
[ '42', value: '42' ]
```. yes, with structure[0] works, but in a structure with a lot of properties it will be hard to associate name with index

Comment: Right. Try `structure[0] = 21`.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your edit. I'm pretty sure that on the web3.js side, when you send a struct to a function, you're really just sending an array. So there's no easy way to get around this.

Comment: Maybe you'd prefer to use `instance.modify([ structure.foo, structure.bar, ...], { from: accounts[0] })`. You still have to list all the properties in the right order somewhere, but you can centralize that code.

Comment: ok, I verified... the order is the same of the struct definition. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As smarx said, using 
`structure[0] = 21` it works, because structure is an array.
With more properties, the order is the same on the struct definition, so, with the struct:

```
struct Example {
  uint first;
  uint n;
  uint last;
}
```

those equals are verified:

```
struct[0] == struct.first
struct[1] == struct.n
struct[2] == struct.last
```

and to change the value we must do:

```
struct[0] = 1 // sets struct.first
struct[1] = 2 // sets struct.n
struct[2] = 3 // sets struct.last
```